# Разрази меня(,) гром

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

"Разрази меня(,) гром" - нужна ли запятая и чем тут является "гром"?
А тут: "Гром(,) меня разрази"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая в обоих случаях  не нужна, потому что это фразеологизм со значением "пусть меня разразит гром, если я лгу". "Гром" не является обращением (это подлежащее), потому что глагол повелительного наклонения  употреблён в значении глагола 3 лица, это не просьба и не призыв, а клятвенное уверение в истинности своих  слов.

Comment: Спасибо. Наверное, это пример не самый удачный я выбрал. Хотелось бы и общий принцип понять.   https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432666