# Подлежащее в повелительном предложении (не фразеологизм)

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

В продолжение [Разрази меня(,) гром](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432655).

Каковы грамматика и пунктуация в повелительном предложении подобного типа, если не причислять их к фразеологизмам? Чем в них является выделенное существительное.

Поцелуй меня(,) **корова**.
Найди меня(,) **счастье**.
**Боже**, Царя храни. (Здесь запятая есть в оригинальном тескте).
**Птица счастья**(,) выбери меня!  (Аналогично).
**Господи**(,) помилуй.

Неужели грамматика и опосредовано через неё пунктуация зависят только от соотнесения с фразеологизмами?!

Верно ли, что подлежащими в предложениях с повелительным наклонением бывают только местоимения второго лица ([Боль моя,] **ты** оставь меня)?

Comment: Граждане, уважайте труд уборщиц. Или с воскл. знаком:: Граждане! Уважайте труд уборщиц!

Answer (score 2):

Найди меня, **счастье.**

Счастье - обращение.Оно лишь называет того, к кому обращается говорящий с побуждением, а не  его действие, поэтому подлежащим не является. Кстати, и предложение называется **побудительным**, а не повелительным.

Побуждение чаще всего выражается глаголом повелительного наклонения, это воля говорящего, обращённая к собеседнику, и тогда подлежащим, т.е. субъектом действия является, Вы правы, только местоимение 2 лица, это диктует его суть, морфологическое значение. Мест.1 лица Я, МЫ указывают на лицо говорящего или говорящего + ещё кого-то, 2 лицо ТЫ,ВЫ на собеседника или собеседника и ещё кого-то, 3 лица - на кого-то в отдалении (форма 3 лица по происхождению является указательной - тот, кто в отдалении).

Повелительное наклонение может иметь формы, выражающие действие третьего лица и первого лица мн.ч. наст. вр. и будущего простого.: Пусть сильнее грянет буря! Да здравствуют музы! Начнём, пожалуй!

При наличии разных оттенков модальности повелительная форма сочетается со всеми лицами обоих чисел: Пропадай моя телега!(поговорка) Приди они пораньше, ничего бы не случилось.(сослагательная модальность)

Answer (score 0):

В общем так.
Вопрос (или основную его часть) я трактую таким образом, что автор хочет понять границу между случаями с обращением и случаями с подлежащим. Речь пока идет только о простых фразах, не ССП и не СПП.

Так вот, я готов признать что четкого объяснения тут нет. 
Разницу между "Пропадай моя телега" и "Птица счастья, выбери меня" я не вижу, если вынести за скобки фразеологичность первого (второе, кстати, уже тоже давно стало фразеологизмом, но запятые не потеряло). И, если уж на песенный репертуар потянуло, есть еще "Не жди меня(,) мама(,) хорошего сына". Вот тут даже авторитетные источники расходятся.

Для практики предлагаю пойти по пути, намеченному Людмилой. Если фразеологизм то, подлежащее - и без запятых, естественно. Если нет, считать обращением и на этом основании обособлять. Все случаи звательного падежа (Боже, Господи, Врачу, Отче) автоматически отходят к обращениям и обособляются вне зависимости от своей фразеологичности. А случаи с местоимениями - строго к подлежащему (хотя в некоторых случаях местоимение тоже выступает как обращение, но в данной теме лучше это опустить).

Понимаю, что это несколько искусственно, но боюсь, что ничего более толкового тут не придумать в рамках существующего описания грамматики.

Если же с чисто академической целью попытаться всё же эту границу между подлежащим и обращением найти, то придется углубиться в дебри исторической грамматики. Я такими возможностями не располагаю, но выскажу предположение, что формы с подлежащим возникли сравнительно недавно и именно на базе существовавших конструкций с обращением, что подчеркивает последовательное употребление в них звательного падежа, сохранившегося в украинском. То есть все эти ваши с Людмилой "громы" и "телеги" грамматически когда-то были вполне себе обращениями, но идиоматизировашись перестали выполнять эту функцию и стали восприниматься подлежащими. Этим, кстати, во многом объясняется и невозможность четко отделить одно от другого.

Примеры использования в ССП (типа приведенного Людмилой "Приди они/люди пораньше, ничего бы не случилось"), где существительное или местоимение очевидно является членом предложения и толкование "обращение" невозможно в принципе, только подтверждают идею о возможности изменения синтаксической роли существительного в таких предложениях.

*Все это, как иногда говорят, "в порядке бреда". Но единственно, я бы совершенно серьезно предостерег от трактовок типа "Запятая потому, что обращение, а обращение потому, что запятая". Понятно, что это замкнутый круг, но вот только за последнее время дважды столкнулся с подобным "упрощением" в вопросах, где не получается сходу посмотреть в корень.*